# Removing Duplicate Data from a Table using MySQL

Tags: mysql, duplicates, sql-delete, any

I am trying to remove duplicate data from my database. I found [a nice example on here of how to do this on an oracle database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771552/finding-duplicate-data-in-oracle#answer-7771733).

The bottom query from that answer (only selecting the duplicate rows) works in MySQL, but the delete query (see below) does not...

```
"DELETE FROM studios as a
 WHERE a.id >
       ANY (SELECT b.id
              FROM studios as b
             WHERE a.name = b.name
               AND a.email  = b.email
            )"
```

The error I get is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a
 WHERE a.id >
       ANY (SELECT b.id
              FROM studios as b
           ' at line 1
```

So, I had a look for the right [delete syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/delete.html) and [any syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html) to use, but couldn't find anything wrong with my query... Any ideas?

Comment: MySQL doesn't like the `AS`operator here. But I don't know how to solve this without aliasing.

Comment: I'm not too sure about the 'ANY' syntax, but have you tried just using the 'IN' statment.  e.g. WHERE a.id IN (SELECT b.id ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query -

```
DELETE t1 FROM studios t1
  JOIN (SELECT MIN(id) id, name, email FROM studios GROUP BY name, email) t2
    ON t1.id <> t2.id AND t1.name = t2.name AND t1.email = t2.email;
```

Comment: Thanks! This did exactly what I needed... Still curious why the original query didn't work? I tried it both with and without `as` in all instances where as` could be used after looking Juergen's answer...

Answer (score 0):

The `AS` operator doesn't work with `DELETE` statements in MySQL.

Try this (unverified):

```
DELETE FROM a using studios a
WHERE a.id >
ANY 
(
    SELECT b.id
    FROM studios as b
    WHERE a.name = b.name
    AND a.email  = b.email
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Juergen! I tried this query, and got the error `You can't specify target table 'a' for update in FROM clause`...