# Duplicate record in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a mySQL db with duplicate records, as from the attached image.

[image]

I am asking for a query to delete all duplicate records based on date + time, for all tables (foreachtables) in db

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093151/removing-duplicate-data-from-a-table-using-mysql/9093456#9093456

Comment: This answer will help you do what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3312098/489560

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I could see, you dont have autoincrement primary key or foreign key.
If you dont have tables with foreign key or relation between, first you can list all your tables. After that, you can create a temporal "mirror" of one table (for eg, autogrill).
Then you can do a:

```
INSERT INTO TemporalTable
SELECT DISTINCT
```

or a

```
INSERT INTO TemporalTable
SELECT Id, Date, Time FROM autogrill GROUP BY Id, Date, Time HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

.

TRUNCATE or DELETE FROM

without where and then put again your data with

```
INSERT INTO autogrill
SELECT * FROM TemporalTable
```

BE AWARE if you have primary keys doing this.

Answer (score 1):

How about you create and `STORED PROCEDURE` for this?

```
 DELIMITER $$

 CREATE PROCEDURE `DeleteDup`()

     BEGIN
         -- Drops the table.
         DROP TABLE bad_temp;

         -- Creates a temporary table for distincts record.
         CREATE TABLE bad_temp(id INT, name VARCHAR(20));

         -- Selects distinct record and inserts it on the temp table
         INSERT INTO bad_temp(id,name) SELECT DISTINCT id,name FROM bad_table;

         -- Delete All Entries from the table which contains duplicate
         -- (you can add also condition on this)
         DELETE FROM bad_table;

         -- Selects all records from temp table and 
         -- inserts back in the orginal table
         INSERT INTO bad_table(id,name) SELECT id,name FROM bad_temp;

         -- Drops temporary table.
         DROP TABLE bad_temp;
     END$$

 DELIMITER ;
```

Please change tablename and column name to your desired schema.

so when you finish creating your `STORED PROCEDURE`, you can use it like this:

```
CALL DeleteDup();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can export your table using this request :

```
SELECT * FROM autogrill GROUP BY id
```

Then, empty your table, and import the export you made before. I don't know another easy way to erase duplicate entries using only a single request.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do this is to copy all the distinct records into a new table or an export. Then delete all records in the original table and copy them back in.

Answer (score 0):

Export NULL if table have autoincrement an for source use alias name, example :

```
INSERT INTO product
SELECT NULL,p.product_sku, 
                    p.product_s_desc, 
                    p.product_desc, 
                    p.product_thumb_image, 
                    p.product_full_image, 
                    p.product_tech_data, 
                    p.product_publish, 
                    p.product_weight, 
                    p.product_weight_uom, 
                    p.product_length, 
                    p.product_width, 
                    p.product_height, 
                    p.product_lwh_uom, 
                    p.product_url, 
                    p.product_in_stock, 
                    p.product_available_date, 
                    p.product_special, 
                    p.create_date, 
                    p.modify_date, 
                    p.product_name, 
                    p.attribute
FROM product AS p WHERE p.product_id=xxx;
```